# Xcopy in C# - how to call it?

Tags: c#

Here I should copy file from nearby local ip address to my local system i have used the following code for copying using the `Xcopy` command and then launching the process but copying through  Argumentsetting in code mentioned if I execute in command prompt it is copying but through code is not copying please tell what is the issue. Any ideas? what through code not copying.

```
string Porocess = String.Format("\"{0}\\xcopy.exe\"", Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString());

string SolutionSettings = string.Format("\"\\\\{0}\\C$\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\Symantec\\Common Client\\settings.bak\"", IPaddress);

string TargetSettings = string.Format("\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\Symantec\\settings.bak\"");

string Argumentsetting = /*"\"" +*/ SolutionSettings + " " + TargetSettings + " /Y";// parameters to launch process

int iret1 = LauncProcess(Porocess, Argumentsetting, Environment.SystemDirectory.ToString());



 public static int LauncProcess(string sProcess, string sParams, string sWorkingDir)
        {
            int iRet = 0;
            Process process = null;

            try
            {

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = sProcess;
                startInfo.Arguments = sParams;
                startInfo.WorkingDirectory = sWorkingDir;
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


                process = Process.Start(startInfo);

                process.WaitForExit();

                Console.WriteLine("Copy has finished.");

                if (process.HasExited)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Process has exited.");
                    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                    {

                        iRet = 1;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iRet = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    iRet = 1;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                iRet = 1;
            }
            finally
            {
                process.Dispose();
            }
            return iRet;
        }
```

Comment: i think you just need File.Copy and File.Delete (*source*)

Comment: string SolutionsrcSettings = string.Format("\"\\\\{0}\\C$\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\Symantec\\CommonClient\\settings.dat\"", IPaddress);
string TargetDirectory = string.Format("C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Application Data\\Symantec\\Common Client\\settings.bak");
             try
               {
                    
                  File.Copy(SolutionDirectory, TargetDirectory, true);
                }
Here File copy when i mentioned above command does not work at all it shows Illegal characters its correct format

Answer (score 0):

check whether source address and destination address are correctly given

```
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.Arguments= @"D:\sourcePath F:\DestinationPath /e /y /I";
  process.Start();
```